# How can I change the background of a selected li in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-lists

I have an unordered list with a bunch of list items. I am setting the background of the selected `<li>` in its click:

```
$(this).animate({
          backgroundColor: '#0000FF'
}, 'fast');
```

When I click another `<li>`, I want to change its `backgroundColor` property, but I want the rest of the `<li>`s to default back to another color. This way, it looks like I am changing the selected state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply do the following:

```
$(this).siblings("li").css("backgroundColor", "");
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/JsVdd/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"#0000ff"},'fast')
        .siblings().animate({backgroundColor:"#000000"},'fast'); // or whatever other color you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mixe of **classes** and **CSS transitions**:

```
$('li').click(function(){)
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})

li{background:#fff; -webkit-transition:all 0.25s linear; -moz-transition:all 0.25s linear;}
li.active{background:#00f;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each.click(function(){
 $(this).css("backgroundColor", "");

});
```